# Countable subcover of half-open cylinders

Tags: gn.general-topology, mg.metric-geometry

While preparing a lecture on dynamic programming principle in optimal stochastic control after the [book of Touzi](http://www.springer.com/us/book/9781461442851), I discovered a gap in the proof of DPP (page 28 of the book).

Here I simplify the relevant place to give a brief idea where the gap lies. The author defines a family of sets
$$
B(s,y) = \{(t,x)\in \mathbf{S}=[0,T)\times \mathbb{R}^d: t\in (s-r(s,y),s), |x-y|<r(s,y)\},
$$
where $(s,y) \in \mathbf{S}$, and $r(s,y)>0$ are some numbers. Further, the author writes, "Clearly, $\{B(s,y): (s,y) \in \mathbf{S}\}$ forms an open covering of $\mathbf{S}$", and then appeals to Lindelöf's theorem to show that there is a countable subcover. However, the fact that $\{B(s,y)\}$ is a cover is false in general.

I've managed to find a workaround. Instead of considering the open cylinders $B(s,y)$, one needs to consider half-open cylinders
$$
D(s,y;r) = \{(t,x)\in \mathbf{S}: t\in (s-r,s], |x-y|<r\}
$$
(note that $t=s$ is now included to the set). 
Then we need the following.

> **Fact 1** Let, for each $r(s,y)$, $(s,y) \in \mathbf{S}$, be arbitrary positive numbers. Then there is a countable family $\{(s_n,y_n),n\ge 1\}$ such that 
>   $$
> \mathbf{S}=  \bigcup_{n\ge 1} D(s_n,y_n; r(s_n,y_n)).
> $$

The proof is as follows. Obviously, $\mathsf{D} = \{D(s,y,r(s,y)),(s,y) \in \mathbf{S}\}$ is a cover of $\mathbf{S}$. The sets $D(s,y;r)$ are open in the topology of the product space $[0,T)\times \mathbb{R}^d$, where the interval $[0,T)$ is equipped with the left half-open interval topology, and $\mathbb{R}^d$ is equipped with the usual topology. Since this space is a product of a Lindelöf space and a $\sigma$-compact space, it is Lindelöf itself. Therefore, there exists a countable subcover of
$\mathsf{D}$.

I don't like this argument too much, since it involves some
topological references I would like to avoid. Therefore, the question:

> Is there a simpler/direct argument of Fact 1?

Comment: Actually the formula in **Fact 1** should read $$\mathbf{S}\subset  \bigcup_{n\ge 1} D(s_n,y_n; r(s_n,y_n)) .
$$

Comment: @PietroMajer, actually not. Read the definition of $D(s,y;r)$.

Comment: Sorry, am I missing something? It seems to me, points $(0,x)$ in **S** should belong  to cylinders that also include points $(-\epsilon,x)$.

Comment: @PietroMajer, I defined $D(s,y;r)$ as a subset of $\mathbf{S}$. This does not matter, of course.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $B_r$ denote the closed ball of radius $r$ centered at $0$ in $\mathbb{R}^d$.

*Claim*:  for any $r>0$ and $\tau <T$ there is a countable subfamily of $D$ that covers $[0,\tau] \times B_r$.

To prove the claim, consider the set $I$ of all $t\in [-\infty, \tau]$ such  that  $(t, \tau] \times B_r$ is covered by some  countable  subfamily  of $\mathsf{D}$. The set $I$ is not empty  (trivially, $\tau$ is in $I$); it is closed, for if $t_j$ is a sequence in $I$ converging to $t$, then also $(t,\tau] \times B_r$ is covered by a countable subfamily of $\mathsf{D}$ (namely, by the countable union of the countable families that covers the sets  $(t_j,\tau] \times B_r$, for $j$ in $\mathbb{N}$). Next, we show that $\min I < 0$, which implies the claim.

Notice that for any $0 \le t \le \tau$ there is a finite subfamily of $\mathsf{D}$ which covers the set $\{t \}\times B_r$. Indeed, the traces of the cylinders $D \in \mathsf{D}$ on the compact subspace $\{t \}\times B_r$  are an open ball covering of it. Also note that this finite family of balls also covers $(t',t]\times B_r$ for some $t'<t$. Therefore it can't be the case that $\min I \ge 0 $.

Since  for any rational $r>0$ and $\tau<T$ there is a countable subfamily of $D$ that covers of $[0,\tau] \times B_r$, the union of these   is a countable covering of $[0,T) \times \mathbb{R}^d$.

Comment: A minor correction was needed: the sentence after "Notice that" is not true for $t=T$, because $\{T\}\times B_r$ is not contained in $\mathbf{S}$ and shouldn't be covered by $\mathsf{D}$. I slightly modified the argument correspondingly.

Comment: I think there was no problem with the former argument, as $T$ belonged to $I$ obviously: the set $(t,T)\times B_r$ is empty for $t=T$.

Comment: Yes, that's ok, but as it was stated, in the case $t=T$ we couldn't deduce  that a finite family of balls covers  $(t',t] \times B_r$  for some $t'<t$ (it should only be true "countable").